# Save as PDF button click trigger multiple download

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I have draw chart based on selection and can save to pdf using button.
 However, when the user select few times, the button clicked trigger multiple download based on the number of selections. It should only trigger 1 download that is the latest selected chart. How to avoid multiple download?

This is the chart:
[image: the chart]

This is the code for the layout:

```
<div class="chart-block-title">Job & Internship by Category</div>
                            <div class="chart-view" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px">

                                <!-- //combo box options to select application filter -->
                                <?php
                                     echo 'Category Group: ';
                                     echo '<select id="category_filter">';
                                     echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="1">Accounting/Finance</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="2">Admin/Human Resources</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="3">Arts/Media/Communications</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="4">Building/Construction</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="5">Computer/Information Technology</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="6">Education/Training</option>';
                                     echo '<option value="7">Engineering</option>'; 
                                     echo '</select>';

                                ?>

                            </div>                  
                            <div class="chart-view" id="categoryname_chart_div"></div>
                            <div class="chart-block-description">The bar chart shows the category of job & internship posted by linked companies</div>
                            <div class="chart-block-view">
                                <input id="pdf-categoryname" type="button" value="Save as PDF" disabled />
                            </div>
```

This is the code to draw the chart:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCategoryNameChart);


    function drawCategoryNameChart(){

                // for category-filter
                $('#category_filter').on('change',function(){
                var select1 = $(this).val();  // category-filter value
                var jsonCategoryNameData = $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $ajaxurl11; ?>",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data: {Value1 : select1},
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false
                            }).responseText;

                var CategoryNameData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonCategoryNameData);

                var optionsCategoryNameChart = {
                             //title: 'Job/Internship Distribution by Category',
                             titleTextStyle: {
                                  color: 'Black',
                                  fontSize: 18
                                },
                                pieSliceText: 'none',
                             fontSize: '11',
                             hAxis: {
                                  title: 'Category Name',
                                },
                             vAxis: {
                                  title: 'Total',
                                  minValue: 0,
                                  gridlines: {count: 4}     
                                },
                             legend: {textStyle: {color: '#464847', fontSize: 11}},
                             tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                             backgroundColor: '#F8F9FA',
                             colors: [ '#3B84BB', '#FFAF45', '#FFE345', '#0CAA63', '#1D40A6', '#F7AE12', '#F75012','#6944C3'],
                             chartArea: {
                                    backgroundColor: {
                                        stroke: '#fff',
                                        strokeWidth: 1
                                    }
                                },
                             height: 300,
                             chartArea: { left:"5%",top:"20%",width:"80%",height:"50%" }
                              };        

                // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
                var CategoryNameChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('categoryname_chart_div'));
                google.visualization.events.addListener(CategoryNameChart, 'ready', function () {
                   btnSave.disabled = false;
                });


                var btnSave = document.getElementById('pdf-categoryname');

                btnSave.addEventListener('', function () {
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    doc.setFontSize(15);
                    doc.text(80, 25, "Jobs by Category");
                    doc.addImage(CategoryNameChart.getImageURI(), 15, 30);
                    doc.setFontSize(9);
                    doc.text(55, 115, "The bar chart shows the category of job posted by linked companies");
                    doc.save('category_name.pdf');
                  }, false);     

                //draw the chart      
                CategoryNameChart.draw(CategoryNameData, optionsCategoryNameChart);

                });


    }
```

Comment: why you fire `click` event in your `change` event? move the `click` out of the `change` event? as each `change`  addEventListener `Click`, I believe you just need to fire once the addEvent Listener

Comment: @joun, move your btnSave.addEventListener code out of $('#category_filter').on('change', function

Comment: Hi @Se0ng11, I moved out the click event as in the edited code, but the button cannot be clicked anymore.

Comment: @veeran, I tried to move btnSave.addEventListener outside onchange function, but it cannot read CategoryNameChart anymore as it is included in the onchange function.

Comment: you need readjust ur code, you can't read the `CategoryNameChart` as it is declare within the change event, hence, adjust the variable to be able to read from outside of the change event, did u need to reassign the value into  `CategoryNameChart` in each change? if not, move it out of the change event, put at the top most

Comment: Yes, I need to reassign the value for CategoryNameChart for each change. I do not know how to take the CategoryNameChart variable to be declared outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is kinda tricky, i had re-adjust it, please test it out, if there is still issue, do let me know if I miss anything

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCategoryNameChart);

function drawCategoryNameChart() {
    var CategoryNameData; //move out the variable 
    // for category-filter
    $('#category_filter').on('change', function () {
        var select1 = $(this).val(); // category-filter value
        var jsonCategoryNameData = $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $ajaxurl11; ?>",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: {
                    Value1: select1
                },
                dataType: "json",
                async: false //since this is async = false, we can ensure that this part will always run first
            }).responseText;

        //var CategoryNameData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonCategoryNameData);
        CategoryNameData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonCategoryNameData); 
    });

    var optionsCategoryNameChart = {
        //title: 'Job/Internship Distribution by Category',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'Black',
            fontSize: 18
        },
        pieSliceText: 'none',
        fontSize: '11',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Category Name',
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Total',
            minValue: 0,
            gridlines: {
                count: 4
            }
        },
        legend: {
            textStyle: {
                color: '#464847',
                fontSize: 11
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        },
        backgroundColor: '#F8F9FA',
        colors: ['#3B84BB', '#FFAF45', '#FFE345', '#0CAA63', '#1D40A6', '#F7AE12', '#F75012', '#6944C3'],
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: {
                stroke: '#fff',
                strokeWidth: 1
            }
        },
        height: 300,
        chartArea: {
            left: "5%",
            top: "20%",
            width: "80%",
            height: "50%"
        }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our pie chart, passing in some options.
    var CategoryNameChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('categoryname_chart_div'));
    var btnSave = $('#pdf-categoryname');

    google.visualization.events.addListener(CategoryNameChart, 'ready', function () {
        //btnSave.disabled = false;
        btnSave.prop('disabled', false);
    });

    btnSave.on('click', function(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.setFontSize(15);
        doc.text(80, 25, "Jobs by Category");
        doc.addImage(CategoryNameChart.getImageURI(), 15, 30);
        doc.setFontSize(9);
        doc.text(55, 115, "The bar chart shows the category of job posted by linked companies");
        doc.save('category_name.pdf');
    });

    // var btnSave = document.getElementById('pdf-categoryname');

    // btnSave.addEventListener('', function () {
        // var doc = new jsPDF();
        // doc.setFontSize(15);
        // doc.text(80, 25, "Jobs by Category");
        // doc.addImage(CategoryNameChart.getImageURI(), 15, 30);
        // doc.setFontSize(9);
        // doc.text(55, 115, "The bar chart shows the category of job posted by linked companies");
        // doc.save('category_name.pdf');
    // }, false);

    //draw the chart
    CategoryNameChart.draw(CategoryNameData, optionsCategoryNameChart);

}
```

Comment: Thanks @SeOng11, will try it. And update to you later, by tonite, maybe.

Comment: Hi @SeOng11...thank you for your efforts. Sorry for taking time to test it. Got jump to another thing